# A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception using FileZilla Server and System.Net.FtpClient

Tags: c#, filezilla, ftps, ftp-server, net-ftp

I am setting up an FTP Server (`FileZilla`) and using the `netftp codeplex project` `System.Net.FtpClient` to connect to it over `SSL`/`TLS` using an `X509Certificate2`.

- I've downloaded `FileZilla Server` [from sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/filezilla/files/FileZilla%20Server/).
- I've downloaded `System.Net.FtpClient v14.06.17` [from codeplex](https://netftp.codeplex.com/).

I think I have isolated the problem, but maybe someone has some additional thoughts as to the underlying cause. A workaround is provided at the bottom of this post.

An exception occurs calling `client.GetListing()` and `client.GetNameListing()`, however, uploading (`OpenWrite`) and downloading (`OpenRead`) both work fine. I've tested many versions of `FileZilla` to isolate what version it started breaking.

- 0.9.42 **works** (2013-12-16)
- 0.9.43 bad (2014-01-02)
- 0.9.46 bad (2014-08-03)
- 0.9.50 bad (2015-03-19) - current

The exception that occurs is:

- **outer message:** `A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception.`
- **inner message:** `The message received was unexpected or badly formatted`

The C# code sample that causes the error:

```
FtpClient client = new FtpClient();
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("blah", "blah123");
client.Host = "127.0.0.1";
client.Port = 21;
client.DataConnectionEncryption = true;
client.EncryptionMode = FtpEncryptionMode.Explicit;
//client.ClientCertificates.Add(cert); // tried both with and without
client.ValidateCertificate += (cli, e) => { e.Accept = true; };
client.Connect();
var list = client.GetNameListing(); // exception on this line
```

On the [Codeplex Documentation](https://netftp.codeplex.com/documentation) page, `jptrosclair` wrote:

> You do not use pem certificates, use p12 instead. See [this Stack
>   Overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13697230/ssl-stream-failed-to-authenticate-as-client-in-apns-sharp) for more information. If you get SPPI exceptions
>   with an inner exception about an unexpected or badly formatted
>   message, you are probably using the wrong type of certificate.

The link refers to `asp.net`, not `FileZilla`. My guess is that `IIS` doesn't support `PEM` and was most likely sending a bunch of gibberish through the stream. However, if you use a certificate format that your server supports, then there should be no problem. As far as I have read, `FileZilla` only supports `PEM` format (or `CRT/CER` which are still `PEM` format).

Also, this doesn't explain why `OpenRead` and `OpenWrite` succeed, but `GetListing` and `GetNameListing` fail.

Regardless, I still tested multiple different certificate generation tools, including `FileZilla's` built-in generator, `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Bin\makecert.exe`, and `OpenSSL (windows)`. The problem still persisted.

Here is a link similar discussion from `skovachev` https://netftp.codeplex.com/discussions/535815
His workaround was to clone the connection before getting the listing.

**Workaround:**

I've tested the following with all `FileZilla` versions listed above. The fix is to download the `System.Net.FtpClient` source code from `codeplex` and in the **`FtpSocketStream.cs`** class edit the following method:

`public void ActivateEncryption(string targethost, X509CertificateCollection clientCerts)`

change:

`m_sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(targethost, clientCerts, SslProtocols.Tls | SslProtocols.Ssl3 | SslProtocols.Ssl2, true);`

to:

`m_sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(targethost, clientCerts, SslProtocols.Tls | SslProtocols.Ssl3, true);`

**(Basically just remove the `Ssl2` flag).**

My guess is something changed in `FileZilla v0.9.43` when the `Ssl2` flag is set when connecting to the server. It is strange that the first time `AuthenticateAsClient` is called it will succeed, but the second time it will fail.

As for uploading and downloading succeeding, the default `EnableThreadSafeDataConnections` is true, which causes the client to be cloned and reconnect to the server. However, `GetListing` and `GetNameListing` do not clone the connection. Putting a breakpoint in the `ActivateEncryption` method, the `AuthenticateAsClient` will be called multiple times. Maybe there is some connection pooling happening under the hood in the `SslStream` class and multiple `AuthenticateAsClient` are causing problems. It's worth noting that the `FtpClient.ValidateCertificate` event is only called once even though `AuthenticateAsClient` is called twice. This gives some evidence of some caching is happening.